# Rate of infection: differential equation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

The rate of change of the number of infected people within a population can be modelled by the following equation:

$$\frac{dN}{dt}=0.0001*N(80000-N)$$

Calculate how many get infected after two weeks?

Is it possible to calculate the number infected with partial fractions or differentiate (Newton's law of cooling) to solve for value N when t=14?

How is this done?

Comment: (i) In the DE, what are the units of time? That should have been specified. (ii) How many people are in an infected state at time $t=0$? That must be specified, else one cannot answer the question.

Comment: If $N(0)=0$ then $N(t)=0$ for all $t$.

Comment: When t=0, N=1 sorry

Answer (score 2):

This is a first order separable equation, so we can get one variable on one side and the other variable on the other. Then you can actually integrate to get rid of those pesky $dN$'s and $dt$'s.

So:
$$\int\frac{dN}{N(80000-N)} = \int0.0001 dt$$

And then you integrate both sides and get something like:

$$\frac{\ln{N}-\ln{(80000-N)}}{80000} = 0.0001 t + C$$

Where C is the integrating factor since we found the indefinite integral. You can find C by substituting in the number of infected people at $t = 0$, which has to be some positive integer otherwise nobody else will get infected! EDIT: You've said in the comments that $N=1$ when $t=0$.

After finding C, if we assume $t$ is in days you can substitute in your value for $t$ and solve for $N$.